# Windows Phone 7 emulator crashes on Windows 8 even after applying the patch

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator, windows-phone-7.1.1

A while ago Microsoft released a patch to allow the Windows Phone emulator to work in Windows 8. The emulator actually still worked for me without the patch (albeit very slowly), but since I applied the patch it crashes every time.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your computer graphics card is Intel mobile 965 express?

I think it is a problem with the drivers for that card

in fact try to change the driver to Microsoft Basic Display Adapter and you will see that with this driver if it Works

Sorry for my english

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the graphics card I have. Man I wish you posted this sooner. Since I had to get the emulator to work ASAP I ended up reinstalling Windows 7 (I already had a dual boot and didn't feel like throwing in a third OS in there). So even though I can't check if your answer solved the problem I'll accept it based on a Google search giving me similar information (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/windowsphone7series/thread/a4bc2373-51ba-4470-9d20-396adf941bba)

Answer (score -3):

Uninstall your VS.
Install VS again.  Then download 7.1.1 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29233).  It works for Win8 x64 with VS10

Comment: It have nothing to do with VS, he can just re-install the SDK.